# using set in mongodb using regular expression

Tags: mongodb

I want to annotate some messages in MongoDB from a social network as spam. 
If I use in the query `_id`, it works, but not using regular expression.

this works for one record:

```
db.group_data.update({_id:"gid_91496835_topic_192"},{$set:{SPAM:true}})
```

this doesn't work for all, but seems to update one record:

```
db.group_data.update({"text":/.*yburlan.ru.*/},{$set:{SPAM:true}})
```

> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

How can I `update`/`set` to all records found by regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `multi` option :

```
db.group_data.update({"text":/.*yburlan.ru.*/}, {$set:{SPAM:true}}, {multi: true})
```

Comment: YES! cool, many many thanks!